# How do I tell /usr/bin/indent on Mac OS X 10.5 to format my C code K&R style?

Tags: c, macos, indentation

On Linux I am used to running `indent -kr ...` to indent C files. /usr/bin/indent on Mac OS X 10.5 does not support the `-kr` option.  Does anyone have a ~/.indent.pro file that would produce results closest to K&R style? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can always just get the original gnu indent program and use -kr option. This is probably best as you will have exact results on both machines.
But still, if you want to use OS X, this are the flags that make up the -kr option:

-nbad -bap -bbo -nbc -br -brs -c33 -cd33 -ncdb -ce -ci4 -cli0
-cp33 -cs -d0 -di1 -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i4 -ip0 -l75 -lp -npcs
-nprs -npsl -saf -sai -saw -nsc -nsob -nss

Comment: All these options are documented in the GNU indent man page and this is the first thing I tried.  indent on OS X does not implement most of these options.

Comment: close expression that works: -nbad -bap -nbc -br -brs -c33 -cd33 -ncdb -ce -ci4 -cli0 -d0 -di1 -nfc1 -i4 -ip0 -l75 -lp -npcs -npsl -nsc -nsob

Answer (score 3):

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=indent) and [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) both have GNU indent packages.

Comment: **@Ned:** I hope you don't mind. I always feel that two separate "<package manager> has what you need" posts are redundant.

Comment: @dmckee: no problem. Fink certainly can a viable option, too.